Grapesjs ckeditor plugin showing warning popup
When I click on edit text it shows a warning popup to upgrade it to 4.24.0-lts.

When I tried upgrading it to the specified version it gives below error.
pluginsOpts: {
      "gjs-blocks-basic": {},
      'grapesjs-preset-webpage': {},
      'grapesjs-plugin-export': {},
      'grapesjs-tabs': {},
      'grapesjs-custom-code': {},
      'grapesjs-parser-postcss': {},
      'grapesjs-style-bg': {},
      'grapesjs-navbar': {},
      'grapesjs-component-countdown': {},
      'grapesjs-tooltip': {},
      'grapesjs-typed': {},
      'grapesjs-blocks-flexbox': {},
      'grapesjs-plugin-forms': {},
      'grapesjs-tui-image-editor': {},
      'grapesjs-style-gradient': {},
      'grapesjs-plugin-ckeditor': {ckeditor: "https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.24.0-lts/standard-all/ckeditor.js"},
    },

[CKEDITOR]: The license key is missing or invalid.

If you suddenly started to see this message, this may mean you accidentally updated CKEditor 4 to the LTS version (4.23.0 and above). This version of the editor is under commercial terms and requires acquiring an "Extended Support Model" contract - https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4-support/

For more information about this error go to https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_errors.html#invalid-lts-license-key

